# nothing happen to XML file when trying to change it after creating jar file

Tags: java, xml, jar

I have created a project in java that writes data to an XML file. It can update, insert, delete, and search data in the XML file.

The problem is when I create the jar file for the project and open it and try to add some data. Nothing is added to the XML file. It seems that after creating the jar file the XML file not linked to the project anymore what should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: wording more understandable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the XML file is in the jar. If that's the case you can still access it and you can read from it. But to write on it you'll have to write in the jar file (like in any zip archive).

Or I'll recommend to keep the XML file outside the jar and it will work to read/write from/to it.

Comment: thanks alot it worked when i kept the XML file outside the jar as you said but if i change the the path of XML file and move it to another folder the same  problem appear in that case i will have to put XML in jar and  write in the jar file am i right there is no another solution ????

Comment: It really depends on how you refer to the XML file. Try with absolute path, I guess you're using relative path.